# Is it possible to use Apache-Zeppelin's Notebook REST-API to execute SQL queries and retrieve the results?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-zeppelin

I've been exploring a bit of Apache Zeppelin and I found the [Notebook REST-API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html).

After exploring the documentation, I couldn't understand if it is possible to send a SQL query via Notebook API, execute it in Apache Zeppelin, and retrieve its results via the same channel.

To do so, I'd be using a Spring Boot server to send the queries to the Apache Zeppelin server and to receive the query results returned.

Is it possible to use Zeppelin to achieve this goal?

Comment: Why would you do that??? I mean there ist basically a rest API for any component in the hadoop ecosystem.

Comment: @m-oliv Did you find any solution to communicate Spring boot to a zepplin ?

Comment: @Medo at the time, the team decided to move onto other solutions and developed our own custom solution in-house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Zeppelin, the unit of execution is a [paragraph](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html#paragraph) and a [note](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html#note-layout) contains multiple paragraphs. Thus to run a query,

1. [create a note](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#create-a-new-note)
2. [create a paragraph](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#create-a-new-paragraph)
3. [execute the paragraph asynchronously](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#run-a-paragraph-asynchronously) (there is a synchronous version as well, but need to consider large query)

Currently, there is no API for updating paragraph text. (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1897) So we need to create new paragraph every time.